# How to use login layout in different pages in opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have already made a opencart login option for user. now I have used the same login form in another page. But I want show the previous login form in that page not creating a new form in front end side. How do I call  that login form ? 
if I do `<?php $login; ?>` in my tpl, will that load the login form in other page?

Comment: Try that and tell us about the result.

Comment: I got `Undefined variable: login` Error

Comment: Your $login variable is not initialized where you use it. Can you show us your code?

Comment: The controller one for the .tpl?

Comment: The code where you initialize $login and the code where you tried to use it and had the error.